# How many natural $(m,n)$ pairs are there such that $m>n$ and 1944 divided by $m\cdot n$ is an integer?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

If $a=1944$ how many $(m,n)$ natural number pairs are there , such that $m>n$ and $$ \frac{a}{m\cdot n}$$ is an integer?
I tried to factor $a$  as $2^3$$3^5$ and solve it with the help of combinations but I get stuck and can't go any further.I can find the solution by counting $(m,n)$ pairs but I would like to know easier and faster way to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Factoring $1944$ would seem like a natural first step.

Comment: As a hint, consider counting all $m,n$, not just $m>n$, and considering cases with $m=n$ and halving something, you should be able to get to the solution

Comment: Now that you know a factorisation of $a$, you also know all its divisors: They will be of the form $2^i\cdot 3^j$ for $0\leq i \leq 3$ and $0\leq j \leq 5$. From this, it is simple to calculate that it has only $24$ divisors, and with the restrictions on $a$ and $b$ even fewer are of interest to you. This could be done by hand, or you could be a bit smarter, such as @Sil is suggesting.

Comment: You've factored it correctly. Do you know how to find the number of divisors of $2^3 3^5$?

Comment: (3+1)(5+1)=24 is the number of divisors

Comment: Now treat each divisor (other than $1$) as $d = mn$. For each divisor, you should be able to determine the number of pairs possible, then consider going along @Sil's line of thought.

Comment: Finding each  divisor and then considering them as $mn$ would take me a lot of time. I need a quicker solution

Comment: Ah, but you can think about them as a collective! Consider: $108 = 2^2 3^3$ is a divisor. How many divisors does it have? ($(2+1)(3+1)=12$) So for that divisor, there are twelve possible $(m,n)$ pairs. None have $m=n$, so six of them have $m>n$ (as the pairs are mirror images). Every divisor is $2^p 3^q$. Now imagine the divisors on a $p \times q$ grid. The same calculation works for each grid point, though for the divisors that are perfect squares ($p \equiv q \equiv 0 \pmod 2$), you'll need to remove the square-root pair before dividing by two.

Comment: (You're now basically looking at the summation of $\lfloor (p+1)(q+1)/2 \rfloor$ across the values of $p$ and $q$.)

Comment: I understand you very well but I think it will take me almost the same time as counting. There are 24 divisors .Considering all 24 divisors and then finding their divisors will take quite a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ignore the requirement $m>n$ for a while. We will consider it later.

Let $m=2^{a_1}3^{b_1}$ and $n=2^{a_2}3^{b_2}$. The following conditions must be fulfilled:
$$ 
a_1\geq 0,\;\;a_2\geq 0,\;\;a_1+a_2 \leq 3 \\
b_1\geq 0,\;\;b_2\geq 0,\;\;b_1+b_2 \leq 5
$$
There are $1+2+\ldots +4=10$ possibilities to fulfill
$a_1\geq 0,\;\;a_2\geq 0,\;\;a_1+a_2 \leq 3$
and $1+2+\ldots +6=21$ possibilities to fulfill
$b_1\geq 0,\;\;b_2\geq 0,\;\;b_1+b_2 \leq 5.$

Therefore, there are $210$ possibilities such that $mn$ divides $1944$, ignoring $m>n.$

There are $2=\left\lfloor\frac{3}{2}+1 \right\rfloor$ possibilities to fulfill $a_1\geq 0,\;\;a_2 = a_1,\;\;a_1+a_2 \leq 3$
and $3=\left\lfloor\frac{5}{2}+1 \right\rfloor$ possibilities to fulfill $b_1\geq 0,\;\;b_2 = b_1,\;\;b_1+b_2 \leq 5.$

Therefore, there are $6$ possibilities such that $mn$ divides $1944$ with $m=n.$ Note: Those are $1,2,3,6,9,18$.

This makes $204$ possibilities such that $mn$ divides $1944$ with $m\neq n.$ For symmetry reasons, half of them satisfy $m>n$ and half of them satisfy $m<n.$ Therefore, there are $102$ solutions.

Following this argument, the general solution for
$$
a = p_1^{r_1}\,p_2^{r_2}\,\cdot\ldots\cdot p_N^{r_N}
$$
with distinct primes $p_1,\ldots,p_N$ is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\prod_{k=1}^N \binom{r_k+2}{2} 
-\prod_{k=1}^N \left\lfloor\frac{r_k}{2}+1 \right\rfloor
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my comments above:

Let $D(z)$ be the number of solutions for a given $z = p_1^x p_2^y$. We can imagine the divisors of any number with only two prime factors as being on an $x \times y$ grid. In this example ($z=1944=2^3 3^5$), the grid is this:

$$\begin{array}{cccccc} 
\fbox{1} & 3 & \fbox{9} & 27 & \fbox{81} & 243 \\ 
2 & 6 & 18 & 54 & 162 & 486\\ 
\fbox{4} & 12 & \fbox{36} & 108 & \fbox{324} & 972\\
8 & 24 & 72 & 216 & 648 & 1944\\
\end{array}$$

But that's just a specific example of a generalization. For any number $n = p_1^x p_2^y$, we have:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} 
\bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{1} & p_1 & \bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{ p_1^2 } & p_1^3 & \cdots \\ 
p_2 & p_1 p_2 & p_1^2 p_2 & p_1^3 p_2 \\ 
\bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{p_2^2} & p_1 p_2^2 & \bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{p_1^2 p_2^2} & p_1^3 p_2^2 \\
\vdots &&&& \ddots
\end{array}$$

(In both cases, the boxed numbers are perfect squares.)

Each divisor in the grid has as divisors all the numbers left and above it. That means that $p_1^a p_2^b$ has $(a+1)(b+1)$ divisors. And each of these divisors of the divisor provides one pair $(m,n)$. If $mn$ is a perfect square, there will be an odd number of divisors, and one pair will have $m=n$, which must be dropped; after that drop, or for non-squares, the pairs will evenly split into those with $m>n$ and those with $m<n$, the latter of which are dropped. For our example, the number of undropped pairs is:

$$\begin{array}{cccccc} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
1 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 9\\
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 12\\
\end{array}$$

Hence each entry in the grid provides $(a+1)(b+1)/2$ pairs, rounded down if the product is an odd number. Then we sum across the grid, giving:

$$ D(n) = \sum_{a=0}^x \sum_{b=0}^y \left\lfloor \frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{2} \right\rfloor$$

For $n = p_1^x p_2^y$. If we temporarily use the total number of pairs (before dividing and rounding), our grid (for any $n$) looks like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} 
\bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{1} & 2 & \bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{3} & 4 & \cdots \\ 
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\ 
\bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{3} & 6 & \bbox[2px, border:1px solid black]{9} & 12 \\
\vdots &&&& \ddots
\end{array}$$

We can see that the total will sum to $T_{x+1}T_{y+1}$, where $T$ is the appropriate triangular number $T_n = n(n+1)/2$. Essentially, we're adding up the upper left corner of a standard multiplication table. The number of perfect squares is $\lceil x/2 \rceil \lceil y/2 \rceil$ (using the ceiling function). So we can rewrite that sum instead as:

$$D(p_1^x p_2^y) = \frac18 (x+1)(x+2)(y+1)(y+2) - \frac12 \left\lceil \frac x2 \right\rceil \left\lceil \frac y2 \right\rceil$$

Hence, $D(1944) = D(2^3 3^5) = \frac18 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 - \frac12 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 105 - 3 = 102$, as in @ReihardMeier's answer. We can generalize to any $z = p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$ as:

$$D(p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}) = \frac1{2^{k+1}} \prod_{i=1}^k (a_i + 1)(a_i + 2) - \frac12 \prod_{i=1}^k \left\lceil \frac{a_i}{2} \right\rceil$$

which is also essentially the same as their generalized answer, though easier to compute I think.